# How to use control key with remote access app using an iPad and bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, remote-control

I use Apple Bluetooth keyboard with iPad. It works well, but the control key doesn't work with remote access program such as iSSH, Remoter VNC, LogMeIn and Remoter VNC. In order to use control key with those apps, I have to touch the 'Control' key on screen then hit the keyboard.

Is there any way that I can use bluetooth control key with those remote access apps?

### ADDED

From http://groups.google.com/group/issh/browse_thread/thread/8b91ce601edb2283/3ed3f672964f1ae5?lnk=gst&q=bluetooth+control#3ed3f672964f1ae5

> The Apple iOS API does not make meta key statuses from physical 
>   keyboards available to apps.  The Option key workaround is only 
>   workable on Apple BT and dock keyboards.  As soon as the API changes 
>   I'll make sure this gets fixed in iSSH.

Answer (score 1):

iSSH has a button on the toolbar for exactly this purpose:

[image: Enable/Disable Option Mapping Button]

Tap that button, view that menu, enable the feature!

Comment: I tried it before, but alt-e doesn't work as Control-E. I guess it can't be a perfect solution.